# How to read a table in a PDF uploaded to the databse and display on a PHP webpage

Tags: php, html, pdf

Please be kind enough to assist me to read a table in a pdf document(after uploading the document to the database) from PHP and display that exact table on a webpage. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Stack Overflow won’t write your solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not know how many you know, what you do so far.
For such reason the answer could bo only very general answer like this following:

Split your problem to few steps:

1. Read PDF from DataBase
2. Get Text from PDF
3. Parse Text to Table

Now ask to your self which step you are able to do ?
Find answer to each step.
Combine them.

You can alose read about here:
https://www.pdftron.com/blog/parsing-extraction/table-extraction-and-pdf-to-xml-with-pdfgenie/how-difficult-is-it-to-extract-a-table-from-pdf

and here you can take a look for some solutions:
https://github.com/pdftables/php-pdftables-api

But you must to know there is no easy + free way to do such things.

You can also take a look here:
https://pdfparser.org/